# Does this cron command run anything other than scheduled jobs?

Tags: cron, cron-job

I have an old drupal civiCRM site (4.7.. i know) that has recently started having issues completing this cron job:

/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s SITEURL -u USER -p "PASSWORD" -e Job -a execute

They can stack up in the process manager (whm) using a lot of CPU.

I'm trying to work out what is causing it - I can manually "run all scheduled jobs" within civiCRM seemingly without issue - is my cron running stuff other than the listed jobs too?

Comment: try running that command directly from the command line as the same user as the crontab file and watch it to see if you're getting any errors or it gets stuck somewhere. I'm guessing there is some kind of context issue.

Comment: What about using cv instead. It's the recommended method in any event and has always worked well for me. https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#cv